# Connecting to OpenLDAP server in vbScript via openDSObject

Tags: vbscript, ldap, openldap

I have code that works correctly to connect to an Active Directory server:

```
Dim oDSObj: Set oDSObj = GetObject("LDAP:")
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDSObj.OpenDSObject("LDAP://ldap.domain.com", "DOMAIN\username", "password", 1)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out the syntax to make this work against an OpenLDAP Server:

```
Dim oDSObj: Set oDSObj = GetObject("LDAP:")
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDSObj.OpenDSObject("LDAP://ldap.domain.com/ou=Users", "username", "password", 1)
```

To be honest, I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to LDAP, so I don't understand what dc vs cn vs ou means (I know they stand for org unit, common name etc) but I don't get when you need to tack that on to queries.

Once I connect to the Active Directory server, the following code queries it:

```
dc = ""
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
oConn.Open "Ads Provider", "DOMAIN\username", "password"            '
Dim rs: Set rs = oConn.Execute("<LDAP://ldap.domain.com" & dc & ">;(& (objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & GetLDAPUserName(sPerson) & "));name,mail,telephoneNumber;subtree")
```

But I realize that sAMAccountName is an AD specific thing, so the openLDAP code will need a different syntax.

The user is 'ldapuser' with a password of 'password', stored here:
ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com

What is the code to connect to that LDAP server and query for account info?

Comment: Hi, U have specified ADS with authentication is working, I managed to sync ADS users without specifying authentication details. How to specify authentication details of ANY domain and get a user's details.

Comment: @itsraja I suggest you ask your question separately as its own individual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
sUser = "myusername"
sDN = "cn=" & sUser & ",ou=people,dc=company,dc=com"
sRoot = "LDAP://ldapservername.com/dc=company,dc=com"

Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sDN, "password", &H0200)

Dim oConn: Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
oConn.Open "Ads Provider", sDN, "password"

Dim rs
Set rs = oConn.Execute("<" & sRoot & ">;(uid=" & sUser & ");cn,mail,telephoneNumber;subtree")

wscript.echo rs("cn").value
wscript.echo rs("mail").value
wscript.echo rs("telephoneNumber").value
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx a lot for your code Michael. 
I've modified it to simply authenticate users (user-password) using the central OpenLDAP server. Here is the code that worked for me (MSAccess 2003):

```
sUser = "TheUserName"
sDN = "uid=" & sUser & ",o=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=it"
sRoot = "LDAP://MyLDAPServer/o=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=it"

Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")

On Error GoTo AuthError
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sDN, "ThePassword", &H200)
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Login Successful"
Exit Sub

AuthError:
If Err.Number = -2147023570 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong Username or password !!!"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```